# Clojure Java Lucene: ComplexPhraseQueryParser with multiple fields

Tags: java, clojure, lucene

Who can I use `ComplexPhraseQueryParser` on multiple fields?

Right now, my code uses `MultiFieldQueryParser.` and looks like this:

```
(defn parse-multi-query
  "Parses term query-string and searches against all indexed-keys
  with AND condition, OR condition being reached with comma sep in input-term.
  Appends to input-term AND account_id
  Parses term (string) and look for result in all index keys
  except when a key is specified in query string (e.g. color:blue)"
  [^String query-string]
  (.parse (doto (MultiFieldQueryParser. ;; ComplexPhraseQueryParser
                 (into-array ["color" "id" "other-id"])
                 (ClassicTokenizer.))
            (.setDefaultOperator QueryParser$Operator/AND))
          query-string))
```

This works fine but cannot do complex queries supported by `ComplexPhraseQueryParser`

And I cannot pass `(into-array (map #(str (name %)) indexed-keys))` to `ComplexPhraseQueryParser`

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why can't you do complex queries?

Comment: I want to run complexe queries on multiply fields `"123456*" AND NOT color: "Blue"` or `id:123456*,other-id:223456*` or `"(john jon jonathan~) peters*"`

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: And I cannot pass `(into-array (map #(str (name %)) indexed-keys))` to `ComplexPhraseQueryParser.` which is want I want

Comment: Is `MultiFieldQueryParser` a `ComplexPhraseQueryParser`?

Comment: no, I don't think so.

Comment: Then what are you trying to do? Please be explicit. This is quite vague. Have you tried passing the array to the parser constructor? Again, what do you need help with?